# I can't upgrade my Mac from macOS Sierra to macOS Mojave. Admin password required

Tags: macos

So because of the quarantine my school sent me a computer to do my work and I want to upgrade the OS. It's running macOS Sierra, and I wish to upgrade it to run macOS Mojave. I can't do so as it keep asking me for administrator name and password.

Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: what computer and year did they give you?  Maybe it's not upgradable to Mojave.

Answer (score 1):

Your Mac is asking for an administrator name and password for a reason. It wants to make sure that only an authorised user is making a major change to the computer as upgrading the operating system software.

You generally cannot work around it. You'll need an administrator username and password to be able to upgrade macOS. You should consider getting in touch with the person/team responsible for this and seek their assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps they don’t want you to do things like upgrades or install other / unknown apps as you might break things they have put in place for your benefit.

It would be a headache for them if you messed up the programs that are installed for remote learning for example.